# How to check type of device (device/simulator) on Run Script phase in Build Settings?

Tags: xcode, shell, build, build-settings, xcode-build-settings

I have 2 versions of some library, one - for real device, other - for simulator.
Can I write sh script to detect on which device (device/sim) Xcode will run application and switch that libraries in Run Script phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your script executed list of environment variables available. One of them is **__IS_NOT_SIMULATOR**.

When building for simulator it have this value:

```
export __IS_NOT_SIMULATOR\=NO
```

When building for device it have this value:

```
export __IS_NOT_SIMULATOR\=YES
```

In build script it can be accessed like this:

```
echo "IS_NOT_SIMULATOR = ${__IS_NOT_SIMULATOR}"
```